# Accessing screen areas from render handler

Tags: python

The code below works flawless, if e.g. triggered by a menu button in a 3D view.

```
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
          if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            for space in area.spaces:
                if space.type == 'VIEW_3D': 
                    space.viewport_shade = 'BOUNDBOX'
```

However, if I bundle it into a function and hook it to a handler, it returns a NoneType error:

```
@persistent
def allBound(dummy):
  for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
      if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces:
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D': 
                space.viewport_shade = 'BOUNDBOX'

 bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(allBound)
```

Returns:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'areas'
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out that inside `bpy.app.handlers.render_pre` the context is different.

For example `bpy.context.screen` is `None`, `bpy.context` has no attribute `active_object` etc. Looks like its very limited when rendering.

What you have access to is `bpy.context.window_manager`. So modify your script like this and it should work:

```
import bpy

def allBound(scene):
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        for area in window.screen.areas: 
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for space in area.spaces:
                    if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                        space.viewport_shade = 'BOUNDBOX'

bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(allBound)
```

Also this now works on a multi-monitor layout.

Comment: I know I shouldn't, but thank you, thank you sir, thank you so much! :)