# How do I render with frame_change_pre handler active?

Tags: python, rendering, animation, scripting

I am working on a Python-driven scientific animation using Blender 2.83.1.  The animation includes four watt meters which are visually represented by `Text` objects.  Each text object has a custom property named "kw" which stands for kilowatts and is the value I wish to display.  The text objects are driven to show the corresponding value using a handler and animated with keyframes.  The color of the text is also changed to red or green depending on the sign of the number.

#### The problem

When I scrub through the timeline it works just fine in preview.  However, when I attempt to render it, the hander does not seem to do anything and the rendered frames are all identical.

#### The ugly workaround

After studying [Execute Python script between rendering animation frames](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34859/execute-python-script-between-rendering-animation-frames) and [Handler frame_change_pre doesn't work in render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168122/handler-frame-change-pre-doesnt-work-in-render) which seem to be describing the same problem, and finding that the proposed solutions there don't work for me, I came up with an ugly workaround shown in the code below as a Python routine called `slow_render`.  For each frame, it sets the frame, temporarily reduces the animation length to a single frame and renders that animation.  This is ugly, slow, and only works if output is a series of still images.  Also, I found that I had to set the frame twice to get the intended effect.  I don't know why.

### Questions

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Why doesn't `frame_change_pre` seem to work during renders?
3. Why did setting the frame twice seem to be necessary?

### Screenshot

[image: wattmeter screenshot]

### Code

The code I'm using to drive this is relatively simple.  It has a handler called `my_handler` which uses the value of the custom `kw` property to alter the text body.  It also has a main routine which installs the handler as a `frame_change_pre` handler and then sets up key frames for the significant events in this simulation.  The meters are named `meter.load`, `meter.solar`, `meter.batt` and `meter.net`.  The first three are driven from data in the script and the last is calculated as the negative net value of the other three.  In other words `meter.load + meter.solar + meter.batt = -meter.net`.

```
import bpy

def my_handler(scene, depsgraph):
    for meter in bpy.data.objects.data.collections['meters'].objects:
        #meter = meter.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
        kw = meter.get('kw')
        color = 'delivered' if kw < 0 else 'received'
        meter.data.body = "{:+.1f} {}".format(kw, "kW")
        meter.active_material_index = 0
        meter.active_material = bpy.data.materials[color]
        print(scene.frame_current, meter.name, kw, color)
            
def slow_render():
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    lo, hi = scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end
    for f in range(lo, hi):    
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f)
        scene.frame_start = f
        scene.frame_end = f+1
        bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
    scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end = lo, hi

if __name__ == "__main__":
    alreadyInitialized = len(bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre)
    if not alreadyInitialized:
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
        meter_name = ['meter.net', 'meter.load', 'meter.solar', 'meter.batt']
        # define the power for (load, solar, batt) at each point
        #         predawn    morning           noon           afternoon         evening      night
        kws = [0.2, 0, 0], [4.1, 0, 0], [2.7, -5.5, 2.8], [3.2, -0.9, -2.3], [5.9, 0, 0], [12.1, 0, 0]

        # calculate net value using list comprehension
        [m.insert(0, -sum(m)) for m in kws]
        # now assign values
        framenum = 1
        for pwr in kws:
            print("Frame: {}".format(framenum))
            for i in range(len(pwr)):
                bpy.context.scene.frame_set(framenum)
                meter = bpy.data.collections['meters'].objects[meter_name[i]]
                meter['kw'] = float(pwr[i])
                print("\t{} = {}".format(meter.name, pwr[i]))
                meter.keyframe_insert(data_path='["kw"]')
            framenum += 30
    else:                
        slow_render()
```

#### Other details

These are probably not relevant to the solution to this, but here are some additional details that may help reproduce exactly what I have here:

1. I'm using the Eevee render engine
2. I'm running on Fedora 32 Linux
3. My default F-curves are set for linear interpolation
4. The background is set to use the Holdout shader (black under Eevee, transparent under Cycles)
5. For Cycles renders, I'm using CUDA and a GeForce GTX 1060 6GB card
6. System is Intel Core i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
7. The two materials used are simple Emission shaders; a red one called "delivered" and a green one called "received" which represent negative and positive numbers, respectively.  Both have Fake Users so they will always exist.

---

### Results

Based on the helpful feedback I received here, [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M80OFFw72PA) is complete.

Comment: Hi. Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167551/sun-object-not-moving-when-rendering-animation

Comment: Have you tried using frame change post?

Comment: @RayMairlot: I read that too, and tried what I think it suggested (see commented out line in handler) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @batFINGER: yes, I've tried both post and pre and have the same problem either way.

Comment: Ed Vid looks great.  Love Kermit the Frog's narration.

Comment: @batFINGER:  :)  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use `frame_change_post`, and evaluated object**

[image]

Test script.

Have added a collection to scene collection containing font objects with a "kw" custom property.

This property has been animated using keyframes.

To get the animated custom property value use the evaluated font object.

```
import bpy

def handler(scene, depsgraph):
    meters = scene.collection.children.get("meters")
    if meters:
        for m in meters.objects:
            print(m.name)
            em = m.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
            m.data.body = f"{em.get('kw', 0):4.2f}  {m.get('kw', 0):4.2f}"
    
#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(handler)
```

Comment: In your opinion, is this a duplicate of the question I mentioned?

Comment: I'm working on applying this to my project, but still don't understand, so I'm unable to fully duplicate it.  Why `post` rather than`pre` and why is the evaluated get only used to retrieve the value?

Comment: @RayMairlot  50 / 50 above uses the evaluated objects (`em`) data, but sets the objects (`m`) data. `m.data.body = str(em["kw"])`   Prob should make more of using an object in the scene. Evaluating some object in `bpy.data` that is not linked to scene is probably not going to work as expected either.

Comment: @Edward  AFAIK the depsgraph passed to pre is always `None`.

Comment: ... in other words its not yet evaluated for that frame.  We are changing the body of the font object linked to the actual object, not that of its evaluated copy. _eg_ `em.data.body`

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  I've read [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html) about `depsgraph` and [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=pre#bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_pre) about handlers, but they're rather terse and I still don't completely understand what's going on.  Is there something else I should be reading?

Comment: For some reason `frame_change_post` is not called when rendering the animation from the render menu. Any idea how to run the handler function every frame while rendering the full animation?

Comment: dunno... the image in question is result of  render animation from the render menu.