# How to accurately measure time in a simulation

Tags: python

I want to measure the time of the simulation. Basically, we are running the simulation at 24 fps, so we think 24 frames is 1 second. However, there was a large error when we measured the time and fall distance in free fall of a rigid body. During the simulation, I noticed that the fps value displayed in the upper left corner of the screen was fluctuating. Is there any way to accurately measure the time? For example, like time.deltatime() in Unity.

Comment: maybe using frame change, like here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186526/how-do-i-render-with-frame-change-pre-handler-active but time constraints are not the same as in a game engine, I suppose.